# Adding pages to a docx label template

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm attempting to modify an existing one page label template (.docx) to add items from a list of dictionaries. Navigating the list and adding text content to each cell in the table is no problem with python-docx module but I need to create a new page which contains a table with identical formatting as the first table. Manually, this is easy to do by tabbing off the last cell on the page.

My idea was to add a page break at the end of the table and then create the table on the new page based on the formatting of the original table. I've not been able to get the code to work for this.

For now I've manually extended the label document by just tabbing to create a bunch of new pages but this is not ideal because the number of items in the list can vary widely (from 5 to ~1500 addresses). I don't want a lot of extra blank pages at the end of half the documents.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few approaches. The one that's best for you may depend on the variation in cell height and so on.

One way is just to keep extending the table and not worry about page breaks. You'd have to get the table settings right, but there are options for whether it can break a row (or maybe a cell) across pages, and you would set that to no. If `python-pptx` doesn't have that option you can just set it in an empty table in the template document and extend that table rather than create a new one.

Another is to insert a page break and add a new table. You would need to set the cell widths explicitly in the new tables. There's no option for copying a table. Assuming there are a fixed number of labels in particular positions on each page, this should be straightforward.